# specifying layout for html posts in jekyll

Tags: jekyll

I am writing my posts in jekyll in  html. I cannot seem to figure out how to specify layout fro the post.
What is the html equivalent of this markdown header

```
---
layout: post
---
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do the same thing in HTML files (and any files) to specify a layout to use.

Answer (score 2):

The layout refers to the HTML templates stored under `_layouts` in your Jekyll directory structure.

If you want to use different layouts for different types of post then you need to create multiple templates in `_layouts`.