# Jekyll posts aren't using layout accordingly

Tags: html, ruby, jekyll, github-pages, static-site

As described in "[specifying layout for html posts in jekyll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18598159/specifying-layout-for-html-posts-in-jekyll)", Jekyll `_posts` should behave as any other page when it comes from its `_layouts`, however it isn't doing this way to me right now.

I'm developing [this static site](https://github.com/artu-hnrq/pripessoaink) to be hosted in a Github Pages and everything else is working fine, but my posts are not.

I also checked the errors in "[Jekyll post not generated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30625044/jekyll-post-not-generated/30625045#30625045)" about Jekyll `_posts`, but the problem wasn't solved.

```yaml
# _posts/2020-06-27-how-I-long-for-summer.md
---
layout: post
title:  How I long for Summer
cover: /assets/img/jhonny.jpg
date: 2020-06-27 20:56:28 -0300
categories: text
---
```

```yaml
# _layouts/post.html
---
layout: default
---
```

```html
# layouts/default.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    {% include head.html %}

    <body>
        {% include navbar.html %}

        {{ content }}

        {%- include footer.html -%}
    </body>
</html>
```

So, even all regular pages are using `default` layout accordingly, my post pages have been rendered raw, as if I haven't declared any layout to them.

[image]

I'm using `minima` theme, but actually I was expecting it hasn't any effect since I overwrited `post` layout.

```yaml
# _config.yml
markdown: kramdown
theme: minima
permalink: :year/:month/:day/:title
```

I tried what I could. Does anyone have a clue about what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is this what it's supposed to look like? https://imgur.com/Bb5sLgP

Comment: Yeah, it is! Have you done something special to right render it?

Comment: Full changes are here: https://github.com/artu-hnrq/pripessoaink/compare/master...ashleyconnor:master

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of your CSS is using relative paths rather than absolute paths and therefore isn't being fetched correctly.

In your various source code files (`head.html`, `footer.html` etc.).

```
assets/js/main.min.js
assets/js/theme.js
assets/css/main.min.css
assets/css/theme.css
assets/main.css // not available
```

Should be:

```
/assets/js/main.min.js
/assets/js/theme.js
/assets/css/main.min.css
/assets/css/theme.css
/assets/main.css // not available
```

Another solution is to use Liquid's `relative_url` filter:

https://github.com/jekyll/minima/blob/master/_includes/head.html#L6

https://jekyllrb.com/docs/liquid/filters/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your attention, Ashley!! I was rounding it sometime and wouldn't solve by myself so fast

Comment: @artu-hnrq no problem ;)